# Rails - Complex data modeling relationship between 3 tables

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, rails-activerecord

I'm facing the following problem, I'm still fairly new to rails and I need your help

I have a table **SALES** with 4 columns: product_id, quantity of the product sold, the seller and the day of the selling.

I have other table **PRODUCT_PRICE** with the list of the products, the price and the month (price changes based on month)

Finally I have other table **PRODUCT** where I have the product, description, and manufactor_id  of the product.

I need to make 2 queries:
- the top 10 manufactors with more products sold in the last month
 - the top 10 sellers with more revenue (using the PRODUCT_PRICE table to calculate) in the last month.

How can I do this with ActiveRecord in Ruby on Rails, I would like to use rails associations to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: what is the relationship between the models?  can you put that code into your question?  Also do `Manufacturer`s `have_many` products?

Comment: how would you do it in SQL?

Comment: Yes, a Manufacturer can have many products. I have no code for the models yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not tested and quite difficult without any further information, but if you have the three models setup:

For the first, based on this query:

```
SELECT manufacturer_id FROM products
LEFT JOIN sales ON sales.product_id = products.id
WHERE YEAR(sales.created_at) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
AND MONTH(sales.created_at) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
LIMIT 10
```

It would be something like this (you don't mention which version of Rails you are using)

```
@top_manufacturers = Product.find(:all,
                                  :select=> 'manufacturer_id FROM products',
                                  :joins => 'LEFT JOIN sales ON sales.product_id = products.id',
                                  :conditions => 'YEAR(created_at) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND MONTH(created_at) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)',
                                  :limit => 10)
```

For the second

```
SELECT sales.seller_id, SUM(sales.quantity), SUM(product_prices.price) FROM sales
LEFT JOIN products ON products.id = sales.product_id
LEFT JOIN product_prices ON product_prices.product_id = products.id
WHERE YEAR(sales.created_at) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
AND MONTH(sales.created_at) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
LIMIT 10

@top_sellers = Sale.find(:all,
                         :select => 'sales.seller_id, SUM(sales.quantity), SUM(product_prices.price)',
                         :joins => 'LEFT JOIN products ON products.id = sales.product_id LEFT JOIN product_prices ON product_prices.product_id = products.id',
                         :conditions => 'YEAR(sales.created_at) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND MONTH(sales.created_at) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)',
                         :limit => 10)
```

If you don't have `created_at` and `updated_at` columns in all your tables then you should add them -  Rails populates them automagically although I guess I should be using your `month` column.